# BSOD while migrating windows xp from physical drive to vhd in virtualbox

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, virtualbox, virtual-machine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [BSOD trying to migrate Windows XP from a physical to a virtual machine](https://superuser.com/questions/132298/bsod-trying-to-migrate-windows-xp-from-a-physical-to-a-virtual-machine)

this is not a new topic , i know, but i can't seem to add comments there
[BSOD trying to migrate Windows XP from a physical to a virtual machine](https://superuser.com/questions/132298/bsod-trying-to-migrate-windows-xp-from-a-physical-to-a-virtual-machine)

Once we are past that, i have to say I used the same https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows guide.
I enabled APIC IO and tried to boot the winXP just to be greeted by a BSOD.

Not sweating, I tried to do a repair install. Interestingly it didn't ask me to repair the partition even though it found the previous winXP install. No matter, i did start the  installation and at some point while installing drivers i get a BSOD again (and again and again) with error

STOP 0x0000000F4

Bammer. I can't even complete the re installation....! any advice?

Thank you!

EDIT (some extra info):
the southbridge is a ICH9 on the original computer (asus p5k/se epu), so i chose the same in the VM.
the disk was on the 1st sata port so i used a SATA controller in the VM as well..

Comment: @Nass: The trick to add comments is to answer a few other questions to get reputation.

Comment: @nass 1) Also see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/330100 (in case you use PATA incorrectly in slave mode)   2) Did you set the BIOS to AHCI and did you load the HDD drivers from a floppy during reinstallation?

Comment: @Hennes thank you for the kb, but its not a PATA port, so it can't be that. I updated the Question.